# Логический отбор строк в dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как написать несколько условий для логического отбора(синтаксис)? 
Вот пример кода, но он естественно не работает, т.к неправильный синтаксис:

```
table[table['wind_direction'] <= 200, table['label'] = 'rainy']
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [Numpy array, how to select indices satisfying multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3030480/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы объединить логические условия, можно `a & b` использовать:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([(100, 'rainy'), (300, 'rainy'), (100, 'clear')],
...                   columns=['wind', 'label'])
>>> df[(df['wind'] <= 200) & (df['label'] == 'rainy')]
   wind  label
0   100  rainy
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать SQL-подобный метод [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   wind  label
0   100  rainy
1   300  rainy
2   100  clear

In [7]: df.query("wind <= 200 and label == 'rainy'")
Out[7]:
   wind  label
0   100  rainy
```

[Документация по индексированию и фильтрованию данных в Pandas...](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)